# How to pass data from one function to another function that is an argument of the first function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the below example, when using `getData();`, is it possible to access the data contained in its object map within a new function – ie. `useData();` – that is an argument of `getData();`?

```
const getData = (useData) => {

  const myData = {
    0: { title: 'Hello' },
    1: { title: 'World!' }
  };

  Object.keys(myData).map((item) => {
    useData();
  });
}

getData(console.log(
  /**
   * Somehow access data represented by `myData` and `item`
   * in above object map along the lines of `myData[item].title` 
  */
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve something like that?

You can call `useData` with some arguments inside `map` function. You can't call some function like `console.log` as argument to `getData` function in this case.

```
const getData = useData => {
    const myData = {
        0: { title: "Hello" },
        1: { title: "World!" },
    };

    Object.keys(myData).map(item => {
        useData(myData[item]);
    });
};
getData(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the default behaviour. But you need to pass a `function`(*console.log*) instead of a function invocation(*console.log()*) and invoke it only later.

```js
const getData = (useData) => {

  const myData = {
    0: { title: 'Hello' },
    1: { title: 'World!' }
  };

  Object.keys(myData).map((item) => {
    useData.apply(console, [item]);
    useData.apply(console, [ myData[item].title ]);
    //or useData(myData[item].title)
  });
}

getData(console.log);
```

```
getData(console.log('something'));
```

is same as:

```
let x = console.log('something');
getData(x);
```